# How to pause a fullscreen video in unity android

Tags: android, button, unity-game-engine, mobile

I have a program that can play video but I need a pause button in mobile. This is my code when playing the video:

```
function Start () {
    Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie ("Rapunzel.mp4", Color.black, FullScreenMovieControlMode.CancelOnInput);
}
```

Please, help me. Thanks!.

Comment: why do you use unity3d? you can do it with simple videoview.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the [FullScreenMovieControlMode](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/FullScreenMovieControlMode.html)

Choose `FullScreenMovieControlMode.Minimal` or `FullScreenMovieControlMode.Full` instead of `FullScreenMovieControlMode.CancelOnInput`

Comment: and then how it will pause the video?

Comment: `Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie` call the native video player of your OS (Android or iOS), Unity can't control the player anymore. All you can do is show / hide the controls of the native video player. With the `FullScreenMovieControlMode.Minimal`, you can show the minimum controls, such as play and pause